# How to take elements of a numeric vector in R, and create a new vector containing seq from 1:(each element)

Tags: r, vector, sequence

Let's say I have a vector called `input <- c(8,5,2)`. I want to create a new vector in which is essentially `c(1:8, 1:5, 1:2)`. I can do it in the following ugly way:

```
input <- c(8,5,2);
newvec <- c();
for(num in input) newvec <- append(newvec, 1:num);
newvec
```

But I feel like it should be doable in one-line, and I'm probably just oblivious to a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier `R` option is `sequence`

```
sequence(input)
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1 2 3 4 5 1 2
```

---

Or use `lapply` and `unlist`

```
unlist(lapply(input, seq))
```

Comment: Answered so quickly I had to wait 10 mins to accept it. Thanks!